# Running annotate or aggreagate on related objects and rendering in template?

Tags: django

I'm trying to do math/find the max/avg,etc. in my views and then render them in the template, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to all work. The calculations need to be done over related objects and I feel like I've tried everything. At my wits end.

views.py

```
def program_detail_view(request, primary_key):
    survey = Survey.objects.get(pk=primary_key)
    maxResp = survey.objects.annotate(max_resp=Max('responseRelevance'))
    context = {'survey' : survey, 'maxResp': maxResp}
    return render(request, 'relevance/programStats.html', context=context)
```

models.py

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    ...
class Choice(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pce = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(4),
        MinValueValidator(1)], choices=radioChoices,
        )
    interest = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(4),
        MinValueValidator(1)], choices=radioChoices,
        )
    responseRelevance = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

template.html

```
    <li>Overall Relevance Score: {{ maxResp }}</li>
```

I expect that the views will output the maximum response from the set of choices, but instead nothing shows up in the template no matter how I try to call it. I've tried the same for average and other annotate/aggregate functions.

Comment: Forgot to add that yes I'm using `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` and things like `{{ survey.choice_set.all.count }}` render fine in the template.

Comment: For a single survey, this should be an `.aggregate(..)` and the `.aggregate(..)` will return a *dictionary* of all the aggregates, so here the dictionary will contain one item: `'max_resp'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either *aggregate* over the given `Survey` object, or *annotate* your survey object that you are retrieving in the first query. The latter results in only a single database query, and is thus likely a bit more efficient.

We thus can `.annotate(..)` our `Survey` object query, and as annotate, we use `Max('choice__responseRelevance')`, since we want to obtain the maximum `responseRelevance` over all *related* choices:

```
def program_detail_view(request, primary_key):
    survey = Survey.objects.annotate(
        max_resp=Max('choice__responseRelevance')
    ).get(pk=primary_key)
    context = {'survey' : survey}
    return render(request, 'relevance/programStats.html', context=context)
```

now we can render this annotated value with:

```
<li>Overall Relevance Score: {{ survey.max_resp }}</li>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Though for some reason it still doesn't want to render on the page in the development server. Where `{{ survey.max_resp }}` should show a number, it's blank.

Comment: @holmesian17: are there any related `Choice`s? Since if there aren't, then the outcome is `None`.

Comment: It looks like there are 5 related `Choice`s, which show when I add in `{{ survey.choice_set.all.count }}`

(Thanks for your help by the way - this has had me tearing my hair out.)

Comment: @holmesian17: and the `responseRelevance`s of the choice are not `NULL`? Is there a specific reason why you set these `blank=True`?

Comment: They're not null. I'm beginning to realize that I left a couple possibly relevant things out of my question. I've got it set as `blank=True` because underneath `responseRelevance` is calculated when the form is submitted by two other numbers.

`def calculate(self):
    responseRelevance = ((self.pce * self.pce)*self.interest)
    return responseRelevance
`
and then it saves it to responseRelevance

Comment: @holmesian17: what happens if you `print(survey.max_resp)` in the view (so for example *before* the `render(..)` call. Then it should appear on the standard output channel of your server program.

Comment: I also have a class that could be relevant (that I'm also just now seeing)
`class ProgramDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Survey
    context_object_name = 'survey'
    template_name = 'relevance/programStats.html'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192233/discussion-between-holmesian17-and-willem-van-onsem).